# Is there any thorough documentation out there for the YouTube v3 Javascript client library?

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-javascript-api, youtube-data-api

I want to create a web app that interfaces with YT, and as a proof of concept I'm simply trying to upload (insert) a caption file on an existing video. [This page](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/code_samples/javascript) got me started with authentication and gave me some hints as to how the client library works, but there are only four specific examples, none to do with captions.

What I would love to see is a page [like this](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/javascript/reference/referencedocs) that describes all the front-facing functionality of the YouTube JS client library. Even better would be examples of all the normal use cases, including managing captions. Is there any good information about this out there?

Answer (score 0):

The link you have is all there is to the client library for javascript ... there's no YouTube specific code like you sometimes find in other client libraries. It's a generic Google ajax library that manages oAuth authentication and handles the tokens so you can send requests and launch your own callbacks. The only other thing you need to do is study https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/ to figure out what your request needs to look like, and pass any relevant parameters to the `request` method of the client library.